# Technical debt ratio on new code always appear 0%

Tags: sonarqube, technical-debt

I have  a problem  related Tech Debt ratio on new code .
when i introduce new code smells , I can  see that Debt increased on the new code however the  debt ratio always  shown  as 0 .
I have  tried changing development code (10 ,15,20) but still i am seeing same issue .

Did i missed any configuration

SonarQube  version : 5.6.6 & 6.7 also .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After couple of days struggle, We found that answer,

if SCM is not configured then "Technical Debt Ratio on new code" won't be computed (details in development story https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5876)

For Maven based project,

- Add SCM tag details in POM file
  (https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html)
- Enable and Add SCM details in SonarQube

  ```
  A ) Go to Administration --> General Settings --> SCM (Left side menu)
       1.set as false to "Disabled the SCM Sensor" and SCM provider "svn"
       2.Add User name and password in SVN
  ```
- Run the Sonar scan your project